# Term for a rhythmically misleading introduction to a pop tune?

Tags: composition, terminology

I enjoy pop music, and when a new tune starts I'll find myself bopping to the beat. I like to think my musical intuition is good, and I enjoy listening to the song build up as expected. However, there are a few tunes out there which have introductions which completely mislead me, such that when the downbeat drops in, it's nowhere near where I think it should be.

Here are some examples (the ones I can think of have rhythm-only introductions, but I'm sure I've heard some with notes as well):

- Queen, ["You and I"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfby6lae-4A)
- Simon & Garfunkel, ["Cecelia"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5_QV97eYqM)
- Steely Dan, ["Bodhisattva"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAEphHf0P-c)

In each of these cases there's a very obvious beat during the main portion of the tune, and when I hear the introduction I get a clear feeling of where the beat will be, but when the beat comes in I find I've misinterpreted it. It's a disconcerting feeling, and distances me a bit from the enjoyment of the tune. I would guess that a course in composing might warn against writing tunes that have this feature (flaw?).

Do songwriters recognize that such an effect occurs, and try avoid it (unless an iconoclast chooses to court it)? And, what would you call such an introduction?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but [Galileo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dI1keSSwdcI) (Indigo Girls) is another excellent example.

Comment: Add the Eagles'  'Take it Easy' to the list. Not misinterpreted, just plain 'missed a beat'!

Comment: The Beatles'  She's a Woman' did that to me the first few times, till I realised that the intro.  was all on the offbeat.

Comment: from a quick listen, Queen does actually start on the 1; Cecilia starts on 4&, making the kick drum the first '1'; Bodhi starts on 1&, leaving you an 'invisible' 1 you have to mentally add. Knowing this intellectually doesn't help you to clap in time, though - you still have to get them to settle in your head the right way round ;)

Comment: As said by Ringo  "I am the click track". Drummers are not machines some can keep better time than others.

Comment: With Cecilia, the first chords coincide with where 'Ce-' goes. An anacrucis.

Comment: The classic example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRilgJDSlMI&feature=youtu.be&t=2m10s. The original drummer was Ginger Baker, who could keep time like no one's business.